# Consecutive days excluding weekends SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on an out of office report, that as suggested shows when someone is off. I’ve been asked to include a returning to work date. So I need to write a query that checks the consecutive dates that the person is off. I’ve managed to find a query which is close, but it trips up due to weekends.
So the default data is :

```
StaffCode   HolidayDate
J.Smith     2017-04-03 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-04 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-05 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-06 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-07 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-10 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-11 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-12 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-13 00:00:00.000
J.Smith     2017-04-18 00:00:00.000
```

When I run the query it returns

```
FirstDay            LastDay
2017-04-03          2017-04-07
2017-04-10          2017-04-13
2017-04-18          2017-04-18
```

But what I want is

```
firstDay                lastDay
2017-04-03              2017-04-13
```

This is the query im using, Is there a way of excluding weekends?

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT HolidayDate d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY HolidayDate) i
  FROM tblHoliday
  WHERE StaffCode = 'j.Smith'
        AND HolidayDate >= '27-Feb-2017'
  GROUP BY HolidayDate
)
SELECT MIN(d),MAX(d)
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,i,d)
```

Comment: FYI:you would be getting more answers(more visibilty),if you include generic tag(in this case sql server ) and then version

Comment: you mean to say mindate and max date from  consecutive date excluding weekend. isn't it ? then why 2017-04-18 is lastday as it do not fall under consecutive. Last day should be 2017-04-13

Comment: sorry @kumarharsh the example i used has a bank holiday in it so the Monday wasn't a working day. but i can ignore those. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a `Dates` table comes into handy. There are many blog posts recommending adding a `Dates` table to a database, for situations where you need to tackle dates.

In order to create a `Dates` table you can use a recursive CTE:

```
;with dates as (
select cast('19000101' as datetime) [current_date]
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, current_date)
from dates
where current_date <= cast('20991231' as datetime)
)
select
    [current_date]
    , NULL [holiday]
    , case datename(weekday, prev_date) 
        when 'Saturday'
            then 1
        when 'Sunday'
            then 1
        else 0
    end     [weekend]
into Dates
from dates
option(maxrecursion 0);
```

As you can see I added two extra columns which might be helpful in the future. One could contain a boolean to point if a specific day is a holiday/national day off - `[holiday]` column.

The 3rd column also contains a boolean to point if a day is a weekend day or not.

So, using the `Dates` table, in a single-query you could do something like this *(it's not pretty)*:

```
-- I'll also create the sample data and store it into a timeOff table
create table timeOff (staffCode varchar(25), holidayDate datetime);

insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-03T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-04T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-06T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-07T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-10T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-11T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-12T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-13T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
insert [dbo].[timeOff] ([staffCode], [holidayDate]) values (N'J.Smith', CAST(N'2017-04-18T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));

-- And now for the query itself (it's not pretty but I came up with it in a short time)

select 
    [staffCode]
    , min([current_date])   [firstDay]
    , max([current_date])   [lastDay]
from
    (select d.[current_date]
        , t.staffCode
        , min(case when d.weekend = 0 and t.holidayDate is null then d.[current_date] else null end) over () [last_date]
    from 
        (select [staffCode]
            , min(holidayDate) [mindate]
            , max(holidayDate) [maxdate]
        from timeOff t 
        where staffcode = 'J.Smith'
        group by staffCode) r
    inner join dates d on d.[current_date] between mindate and maxdate
    left join timeOff t on d.[current_date] = t.holidayDate ) r
where [current_date] < [last_date]
    and staffCode is not null
group by staffCode;
```

Comment: I've actually tried implementing this however if there is another request in later in the year it uses that date as the last day...

Comment: @GPH I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Maybe you can add more details to your question and the expected output?

Comment: ok, if there are 2 holiday requests. one for a week in june and one for a week in december the query just looks at the last date it can see. which in this case is december. so the Holiday startdate shows as 1st June and the End date shows as december..

Comment: @GPH Ok, then it means that your expected output is wrong. You would be looking for `2017-04-03  ... 2017-04-13`, right?

Comment: @GPH You're lucky I kept my answer from a few days ago. And what I originally understood from your question when I skimmed through it. Give me a minute to re-edit.

Comment: @GPH You should find my current answer to be what you were looking for initially.